# how to select a custom central-meridian in d3?

Tags: d3.js

How can I select my own, custom central-meridian for a d3-map-projection?
As an absolute newbie I started with this example from Mike Bostock:
http://bl.ocks.org/3734333

It shows a Miller-Projection of the world with a central meridian of 0 degrees.
How do I center this (and other projections) in d3 to a custom meridian, eg. 10 degrees east from Greenwich?

I tried using projection.center([0,-10]), but this does not work.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]projection.rotate([longitude,lattitude]) does the trick, eg. .rotate([-10,0]) sets the central meridan to 10 degrees east of greenwich

EDIT 1:
BUT: Now  I have this thick, fat  line at 180 degrees, which I want to get rid of.

EDIT 2:
we can style this with the following css-rule

```
.foreground {
  fill: none;
  stroke: color;
  stroke-width: xy px;
}
```

use the same color for stroke and the same pixel-width for stroke-width then for the graticule[image]